# Conditional update across multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

New to SQL so still learning all there is to offer.

I'm bringing in data from multiple sources and building a unique identifier table.
Several fields must be populated in order of precedence (i.e. the first datasource is preferred, then 2nd and so on).

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
UPDATE
    TABLE1 AS DIMTABLE
SET
    FIRSTNAME = ifnull( FIRSTNAME, RAWTABLE.FIRSTNAME )
    , DIMTABLE.MIDDLENAME = ifnull( DIMTABLE.MIDDLENAME, RAWTABLE.MIDDLENAME )
    , DIMTABLE.LASTNAME = ifnull( DIMTABLE.LASTNAME, RAWTABLE.LASTNAME )
    , DIMTABLE.GENDER = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.GENDER, RAWTABLE.GENDER )
    , DIMTABLE.DOB = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.DOB, RAWTABLE.DOB )
    , DIMTABLE.PHONE1 = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.PHONE1, RAWTABLE.PHONE1 )
    , DIMTABLE.PHONE2 = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.PHONE2, RAWTABLE.PHONE2 )
    , DIMTABLE.EMAIL = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.EMAIL, RAWTABLE.EMAIL )
    , DIMTABLE.FAX = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.FAX, RAWTABLE.FAX )
FROM
    TABLE2 AS RAWTABLE
    WHERE 
        RAWTABLE.ID_SOURCE_ID = 9
        AND DIMTABLE.UID = RAWTABLE.UID
```

I have a sequence of these statements.  One for each RAWTABLE.IDSOURCE_ID = 10,11,15...

The result is that the null fields I'm trying to update, remain null.

I was hoping something like this was possible to avoid multiple passes over the table.
I'm struggling with this approach which usually means there must be a better way

Answer (score 1):

One option is to prepare rows first(giving preference first NOT NULL value in a column per UID):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE RAWTABLE_SINGLE_UID
AS
SELECT DISTINCT
  UID
 ,FIRST_VALUE(FIRSTNAME) IGNORE_NULLS 
       OVER(PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY SOURCE_ID) AS FIRSTNAME
 ,FIRST_VALUE(LASTNAME) IGNORE_NULLS 
       OVER(PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY SOURCE_ID) AS LASTNAME
 ,...
FROM TABLE2
WHERE SOURCE_ID IN (9,10,11,15);
```

Warning `QUALIFY` does not guarantee first non-null value per column but entire row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE RAWTABLE_SINGLE_UID
AS
SELECT *
FROM TABLE2
WHERE SOURCE_ID IN (9,10,11,15)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY SOURCE_ID) = 1
```

And then perform update:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 AS DIMTABLE
SET   FIRSTNAME = ifnull( FIRSTNAME, RAWTABLE.FIRSTNAME )
    , DIMTABLE.MIDDLENAME = ifnull( DIMTABLE.MIDDLENAME, RAWTABLE.MIDDLENAME )
    , DIMTABLE.LASTNAME = ifnull( DIMTABLE.LASTNAME, RAWTABLE.LASTNAME )
    , DIMTABLE.GENDER = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.GENDER, RAWTABLE.GENDER )
    , DIMTABLE.DOB = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.DOB, RAWTABLE.DOB )
    , DIMTABLE.PHONE1 = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.PHONE1, RAWTABLE.PHONE1 )
    , DIMTABLE.PHONE2 = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.PHONE2, RAWTABLE.PHONE2 )
    , DIMTABLE.EMAIL = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.EMAIL, RAWTABLE.EMAIL )
    , DIMTABLE.FAX = IFNULL( DIMTABLE.FAX, RAWTABLE.FAX )
FROM RAWTABLE_SINGLE_UID AS RAWTABLE
WHERE DIMTABLE.UID = RAWTABLE.UID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `LEFT JOIN` for this purpose with `COALESCE:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 main
    SET FIRSTNAME = COALESCE(T1.FIRSTNAME, t2.FIRSTNAME, t3.FIRSTNAME),
        . . ..
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 T2
     ON T2.UID = T1.UID LEFT JOIN
     TABLE3 t3
     ON t3.UID = T1.UID
WHERE T1.ID_SOURCE_ID = 9 AND
      T1.UID = MAIN.UID;
```

This is assuming the following:

- You want to update `ID_SOURCE_ID = 9` in the main table.
- `UID` is a unique id in all the tables.

The secondary tables do not need to have all the `UID`s.